# Cannot import python module (shared object) in Windows 10, but can do so in Linux

Tags: python, linux, windows, import, conda

I am trying to set up my Windows 10 dev environment same as my Linux, as I want to work with pyCharm.

I did a pip install for some local packages for Linux and Windows - while I can import just fine in Linux, I am having trouble doing that in Windows. For example:

Linux - all good

```
(behave) linux:/home/<my_username>/engines $ which python
~/anaconda3/envs/behave/bin/python
(behave) linux:/home/<my_username>/engines $ python --version
Python 3.7.6
(behave) linux:/home/<my_username>/engines $ pip show protogen
Name: protogen
Version: 2.1
Summary: Pybinds for protogen protocols
Home-page: UNKNOWN
Author: Developer
Author-email: UNKNOWN
License: UNKNOWN
Location: /home/<my_username>/anaconda3/envs/behave/lib/python3.7/site-packages
Requires:
Required-by: order-entry
(behave) linux:/home/<my_username>/engines $ python
Python 3.7.6 (default, Jan  8 2020, 19:59:22)
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import protogen
>>>
```

Windows 10

```
(behave) C:\Users\<my_username>> $ where python
C:\Users\<my_username>\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\envs\behave\python.exe
T:\python\python.exe
(behave) linux:/home/<my_username>/engines $ python --version
Python 3.7.6
(behave) linux:/home/<my_username>/engines $ pip show protogen
Name: protogen
Version: 2.1
Summary: Pybinds for protogen protocols
Home-page: UNKNOWN
Author: Developer
Author-email: UNKNOWN
License: UNKNOWN
Location: C:\Users\<my_username>\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\envs\behave\lib\site-packages
Requires:
Required-by: order-entry
(behave) C:\Users\<my_username>>python
Python 3.7.6 (default, Jan  8 2020, 20:23:39) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import protogen
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\<my_username>\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\envs\behave\lib\site-packages\protogen\__init__.py", line 194, in <module>
    aquisatp        = get_fixed_proto('AquisATP')
  File "C:\Users\<my_username>\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\envs\behave\lib\site-packages\protogen\__init__.py", line 182, in get_fixed_proto
    proto = importlib.import_module(f'.protos.{name}', __name__)
  File "C:\Users\<my_username>\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\envs\behave\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'protogen.protos.AquisATP'
```

AquisATP is a shared object that is located in: C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\envs\behave\lib\site-packages\protogen\protos\AquisATP.so

Currently I set my PYTHONPATH to C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\envs\behave\lib\site-packages

Comment: Are you sure you pip install it on the same python version that you are running on the shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar issues when I switched to pycharm as well. To me is seems like the environment (Project Interpreter) that we selected affects what we install and how. Have to tried to conda install them and see if that works?

There is also a possibility that AquisATP is available only on Linux and not on Windows.

Comment: I am not sure if I am reading it right that .so is for Linux and .dll is for Windows.

Comment: @ArMonk I am just saying that there are cases where a py module is available for one operating system and not for another one. I may not be your case, but I can't check it as I am not really familiar with the lib.

Comment: I will give you a check mark because I can now confirm the library is only intended for Linux but not for Windows.

Comment: @ArMonk, many thanks for that. Glad that you managed to find out!